# Delta Lake Table Metadata Sync on Athena

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, amazon-athena

now that we can query delta lake tables from Athena without having to generate manifest files, does it also take care of automatically syncing the underlying partitions? I see MSCK REPAIR is not supported for delta tables. Or do I need to use a Glue crawler for this?

I am confused because of these two statements from [Athena documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/delta-lake-tables.html)

1. You can use Amazon Athena to read Delta Lake tables stored in Amazon S3 directly without having to generate manifest files or run the `MSCK REPAIR` statement.
2. Athena synchronizes table metadata, including schema, partition columns, and table properties, to AWS Glue if you use Athena to create your Delta Lake table. As time passes, this metadata can lose its synchronization with the underlying table metadata in the transaction log. To keep your table up to date, you can use the AWS Glue crawler for Delta Lake tables.